# Search for field name ends with

Tags: odata

I am new to OData and I have a scenario to search for field name that contains words I am looking for. Below is the data I would like to search for the field name that ends with `_isApproved`. I am not sure if it possible to do such search.

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "address": "123 Example Dr.",
    "city": "Frederick",
    "zipcode": 654334,
    "extension_345435423_isApproved": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Smith",
    "address": "124 Example Dr.",
    "city": "Frederick",
    "zipcode": 654374
  }
]
```

Comment: So you want a filter which finds all objects which have a property that ends in `_isApproved`? Or do you want to filter based on the content of that field?

Comment: correct. I am looking for a filter that finds all the object that ends with `isApproved`.

Comment: I doubt that is possible using the default OData URI syntax.